# Swapping nodes in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, swap, singly-linked-list

I tried to make function(swapNodes) for swapping nodes in linked list.
Here i stored previous and next addresses of nodes which are to be swapped.
But my code stucked in infinite loop.  
 

Can this code be made as working one or it is a wrong approach?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node =
        (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}


void printList(struct Node *node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void swapNodes(struct Node** headr,int key1,int key2)
{
    struct Node* temp1 = *headr;
    struct Node* temp2 = *headr;

    if(key1 == key2)
    return;

    struct Node* prev1 =NULL;
    struct Node* next1 =temp1;
    while(temp1->data !=key1 && next1 !=NULL)
    {
    prev1 =temp1;
    temp1 =temp1->next;
    next1 =temp1->next;
    }
    struct Node* prev2 =NULL;
    struct Node* next2 =temp2;
    while(temp2->data !=key2 && next2 !=NULL)
    {
    prev2 =temp2;
    temp2 =temp2->next;
    next2 =temp2->next;
    }
    if(next1 == NULL||next2 == NULL)
    return;

    prev1->next =temp2;
    temp2->next =next1;
    prev2->next =temp1;
    temp1->next =next2;
}
int main()
{
    struct Node *start = NULL;

    push(&start, 7);
    push(&start, 6);
    push(&start, 5);
    push(&start, 4);
    push(&start, 3);
    push(&start, 2);
    push(&start, 1);

    printf("\n Linked list before calling swapNodes() ");
    printList(start);

    swapNodes(&start, 4, 3);

    printf("\n Linked list after calling swapNodes() ");
    printList(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running on a debugger with some sample test cases.

Comment: If you are allowed to swap data then you can do that to avoid errors due to pointer manipulation.

Comment: @ilz0R The reference you pointed is useless for this question.

Comment: @Bhart Mittal  The function has undefined behavior because temp1 or temp2 can be equal to NULL.

Comment: Although one of the duplicate questions is tagged C++, the operational code is the same as C code (but the swapping function does contain a `cout << … << endl;` line, which is pure C++).  That covers the more general case; the pure C question covers a more limited case of swapping adjacent nodes.  Note that one of the suggestions in the C++ question is to swap payloads instead of swapping the pointers around — that has great merit since it can be done without needing to know anything about the nodes prior to the swapped nodes.

Comment: Mr @VladfromMoscow: Why is this remotely different from the questions I closed this as a duplicate of?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was not satisfied with the answers in the provided references.:) One of the references if I am not mistaken is about doubly-linked lists and other does not contain a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The function has undefined behavior because it does not take into account that for example `headr` can be equal to `NULL` or `prev1` and `prev2` can be equal to `NULL`.

It would be good to write one more function that finds the node that corresponds to the given data.

Nevertheless the function `swapNodes` can be written the following way. It finds nodes to be swapped and then swaps pointers to the nodes and their data members `next`.

Here you are

```
void swap( struct Node **first, struct Node **second )
{
    struct Node *tmp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp;
}

void swapNodes( struct Node **headr, int key1, int key2 )
{
    if ( key1 == key2 ) return;

    struct Node **first = headr;

    while ( *first && ( *first )->data != key1 ) first = &( *first )->next;

    if ( *first == NULL ) return;

    struct Node **second = headr;

    while ( *second && ( *second )->data != key2 ) second = &( *second )->next;

    if ( *second == NULL ) return;

    swap( first, second );
    swap( &( *first )->next, &( *second )->next );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node =
        (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

void printList(struct Node *node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void swap( struct Node **first, struct Node **second )
{
    struct Node *tmp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp;
}

void swapNodes( struct Node **headr, int key1, int key2 )
{
    if ( key1 == key2 ) return;

    struct Node **first = headr;

    while ( *first && ( *first )->data != key1 ) first = &( *first )->next;

    if ( *first == NULL ) return;

    struct Node **second = headr;

    while ( *second && ( *second )->data != key2 ) second = &( *second )->next;

    if ( *second == NULL ) return;

    swap( first, second );
    swap( &( *first )->next, &( *second )->next );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    struct Node *start = NULL;

    push(&start, 7);
    push(&start, 6);
    push(&start, 5);
    push(&start, 4);
    push(&start, 3);
    push(&start, 2);
    push(&start, 1);

    printf("\n Linked list before calling swapNodes() ");
    printList(start);

    swapNodes(&start, 4, 3);

    printf("\n Linked list after  calling swapNodes() ");
    printList(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
 Linked list before calling swapNodes() 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
 Linked list after  calling swapNodes() 1 2 4 3 5 6 7
```

In fact the function `swapNodes` as it is written (without a separate function that finds nodes for a given data) does two things: it 1) finds two nodes and it 2) swaps them. Searching of the nodes can be unsuccessful. So the function should report to the user whether nodes were swapped. In this case it is desirable to declare the function as having return type `int`.

For example

```
int swapNodes( struct Node **headr, int key1, int key2 )
{
    int success = key1 != key2;

    if ( success )
    {        
        struct Node **first  = headr;
        struct Node **second = headr;

        while ( *first && ( *first )->data != key1 ) first = &( *first )->next;

        success = *first != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {            
            while ( *second && ( *second )->data != key2 ) second = &( *second )->next;

            success = *second != NULL;
        }

        if ( success )
        {            
            swap( first, second );
            swap( &( *first )->next, &( *second )->next );
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

If to write a separate function that searches a node as it was mentioned above then the function that swaps nodes will look more clear and simpler.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node =
        (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

void printList(struct Node *node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void swap( struct Node **first, struct Node **second )
{
    struct Node *tmp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp;
}

struct Node ** find( struct Node **headr, int data )
{
    while ( *headr && ( *headr )->data != data ) headr = &( *headr )->next;

    return headr;
}

void swapNodes( struct Node **first, struct Node **second )
{
    swap( first, second );
    swap( &( *first )->next, &( *second )->next );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    struct Node *start = NULL;

    push(&start, 7);
    push(&start, 6);
    push(&start, 5);
    push(&start, 4);
    push(&start, 3);
    push(&start, 2);
    push(&start, 1);

    printf("\n Linked list before calling swapNodes() ");
    printList(start);

    struct Node **first;
    struct Node **second;

    if ( ( first = find( &start, 4 ) ) && ( second = find( &start, 3 ) ) )  swapNodes( first, second );

    printf("\n Linked list after  calling swapNodes() ");
    printList(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite you `swapNodes` function a bit:

```
void swapNodes(struct Node** headr, int key1, int key2)
{
    struct Node* temp1 = *headr;
    struct Node* temp2 = *headr;

    if(key1==key2)
        return;

    struct Node* prev1=NULL;
    while(temp1 && temp1->data!=key1)
    {
        prev1=temp1;
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    struct Node* prev2=NULL;
    while(temp2 && temp2->data!=key2)
    {
        prev2=temp2;
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }

    if(temp1==NULL || temp1==NULL)
        return;

    // temp1 is a head
    if (prev1 == NULL) {
        *headr = temp2;
    } else {
        prev1->next = temp2;
    }

    // temp2 is a head
    if (prev2 == NULL) {
        *headr = temp1;
    } else {
        prev2->next = temp1;
    }

    struct Node *buff = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = buff;
}
```

As you can see you don't need `next1` and `next2` pointers. But you must check if `temp1` or `temp2` is a head: it is a special case when you need to replace head with another node. The rest is trivial - just swap nodes via buffer node.