# Encountered a while sorting linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I'm trying to sort a linked list with nodes containing animal names and their weight in increasing alphabetical order. I implemented a function to do it, but I'm getting unexpected output. I really tried debugging it for quite a while, but I'm struggling to find the problem. I would really appreciate any input. My code is as follows:

```
typedef struct Animal_Info{
    char animal_name[1000];
    float animal_weight;
}AnimalInfo;

typedef struct my_node{
    AnimalInfo info;
    struct my_node *next;
}Animal_Node;

Animal_Node *sortAnimalList(Animal_Node *head)
{
    Animal_Node *a = NULL;
    Animal_Node *b = NULL;
    a = head;
    b = head->next;
    char name_copy[MAX_STR_LEN];
    float weight_copy;
    while (a != NULL){
        while (b != NULL){
            if (strcmp(a->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_name) > 0){
                strcpy(name_copy, b->info.animal_name);
                weight_copy = b->info.animal_weight;
                deleteNode(b->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_weight, head); // finds and deletes the node
                insertNode(name_copy, weight_copy, head); // insert at head of linked list
            }
            else if (strcmp(a->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_name) == 0){
                weight_copy = 1.0; /* "do nothing" statement */
            }
            b = b->next;
        }
        a = a->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What unexpected results are you getting? What input are you passing it? And what debugging steps have you tried so far? I'd add some `printf()`s here & there to see what's going on with a small input set.

Comment: I'm just passing the head of an arbitrary linked list of animal information that I created. The function is not returning anything at all in the terminal, so I'm guessing there's an infinite loop (which I can't find)

Comment: You can adapt the mergesort in [Singly Linked List of Integers (mergesort)](https://pastebin.com/CsBYkjrq) to work with your struct by providing a compare function to sort struct by the desired member. If your list exceeds ~100,000 nodes you will need to change to a bottom-up mergesort.

Comment: Would bubblesort work?

Comment: It really helps if you create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
A key component of an MCVE is the input data, the actual output, and the expected output.  That is all totally missing at the moment.

Comment: It seems odd to use `InsertMovieReview()` while working with animals.

Comment: You could most easily use a bubble sort on an array.  However, you could adapt it to work on a list.  You have to arrange for the code to take a sequence of list entries like A⟶C⟶B and move links (or content) so you end up with A⟶B⟶C.  Watch out for the ends of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things in your code that looks strange.

First this part:

```
        else if (strcmp(a->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_name) == 0){
            weight_copy = 1.0; /* "do nothing" statement */
        }
```

When it is doing nothing simply delete it!

Now look at this and my inline comments:

```
Animal_Node *sortAnimalList(Animal_Node *head)
{
    Animal_Node *a = NULL;
    Animal_Node *b = NULL;
    a = head;
    b = head->next;
    char name_copy[MAX_STR_LEN];
    float weight_copy;
    while (a != NULL){
        while (b != NULL){
            if (strcmp(a->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_name) > 0){
                strcpy(name_copy, b->info.animal_name);
                weight_copy = b->info.animal_weight;

                // Here you delete node b
                deleteNode(b->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_weight, head);
                insertNode(name_copy, weight_copy, head);
            }

            // Here you use node b
            b = b->next;
        }
        a = a->next;
    }
}
```

When you get into the code that deletes node b, you can't use the node in the statement `b = b->next;` Simply because `b` no longer points to a valid node.

When `b` becomes NULL, you do `a = a->next;` but you don't change `b` so the inner-loop will not execute.

I assume you need something like:

```
    while (a != NULL){

        // Assign new value to b whenever a has changed
        b = a->next;

        while (b != NULL){
            if (strcmp(a->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_name) > 0){
                strcpy(name_copy, b->info.animal_name);
                weight_copy = b->info.animal_weight;

                // Here you delete node b
                deleteNode(b->info.animal_name, b->info.animal_weight, head);
                insertNode(name_copy, weight_copy, head);
            }

            // Here you use node b
            b = b->next;
        }
        a = a->next;
    }
```

Finally I think your algorithm is wrong. When you change the linked list you always puts the element in front of the list. That wont work. Consider:

```
 "c" -> "a" -> "b"
```

So the steps would be:

```
compare "c" and "a"
delete "a" and insert "a" in front, i.e. you have "a" -> "c" -> "b"

compare "c" and "b"
delete "b" and insert "b" in front, i.e. you have "b"->"a" -> "c"
```

So the resulting list is `"b"->"a" -> "c"` which isn't sorted.

You need to reconsider your algorithm.

Instead of "delete and insert-in-front", you could consider to swap the nodes. Maybe this can help [Swapping nodes in linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904628/swapping-nodes-in-linked-list)